# @Transactional commits transactions in wrong order. Delete is not flushing before save

Tags: sql-server, jpa, transactional, mssql-jdbc

I have got Unique constraints on 2 columns of the table on which am performing the update. So when I have a `.delete()` and a new `.save()` operation, the delete is not flushed before `.save()` and I get.....

> "Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UK539hbsolqnvttv6xbimjmij87'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object '$TABLE_NAME'. The duplicate key
>   value is (uniqConstColum1, uniqConstColum2)"

Is there an option provided by Spring in @Transactional to specify force flush after every transaction within the method?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use .commit() in your connection before use the save method?

Comment: You can call flush() to execute the SQL statements after delete()